# Virtualbox stops when start

Tags: virtualbox

When I start my VirtualBox on Ubuntu 13.10, it stops on "Starting virtual machine 0%"  [image]

I can't use my Virtual Box

I already to remove and install again, but the problem keep.

Comment: so are you saying that your VB vrtual machine worked fine before you upgraded?
Could you also link to us the contents of the last logfile that was generated? your logs will be in a subdir of your VB directory called Logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced the same problem.

Upgraded from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 and Virtual Box could not start any virtual machines anymore.

It displayed the "0 % dialog" as in the pic for a couple minutes, then switched to a "20 %" progressbar, and after that nothing happened.

CPU usage for VirtualBox is 2% or less.

The last two lines from the VBox.log are:

```
00:00:16.340506 Audio: Trying driver 'pulse'.
00:00:16.350789 Pulse: Audio input/output stopped!
```

Therefore I disabled the soundcard in the virtualmachine setup, and now VirtualBox will start virtual machines again.

Great!